# Flow/SharePoint List limitations

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, sharepoint-list, power-automate

I'm planning a company wide software rollout and wanted to control the communication with Lists and Power Automate. All employees (~9000) would be stored within a SharePoint List containing email, date, name and some additional information.

Now I'd like to run a daily Flow which

- filters the list by current date
- iterates the remaining entries
- sends an email to each user (about 800 per day) from an O365 group mailbox
- writes a control value in the SharePoint List
- BONUS: sends a summary to me

I also want to pre-fill the whole list (~9000 entries) with a seperate Flow which checks the Office Profile per email-adress and fetches firstname, department etc. so I don't have to do this per send email on the rollout.

Now my question is:
**Do I run into any limitation with Flow/Lists/Outlook?**
(Our company has a E3 licence)

Comment: Depending how many actions are in your flow, you might run into 2000 actions/24 hours limit. And you might need to purchase add on. You can take look [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/api-request-limits-allocations)

Comment: What is considered as a single action? Getting user profile, writing one or multiple fields in a list, IF-THEN-block, are these all unique actions? Is there an overview what is considered as a single action?

Comment: There is no MS documented definition (as I couldn't find online) as to what constitutes an **Action** in Power Automate. However, my conversation with MS support revealed that even a **variable** declaration in the flow is considered an action. I believe you could monitor the actions consumed by your flow  in the Admin Console in your tenant (I'm not admin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the comments:

1. The first limit you will exceed is the **5000** [list view threshold](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/items-exceeds-list-view-threshold), if you have plans for management directly in the list.
2. The [sending limits for Exchange Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/exchange-online-service-description/exchange-online-limits#sending-limits) is **10,000 recipients per day** so that should not be a problem.
3. Flow has a **500** limit on actions and allowed nesting depth for actions **8** for a single definition, where condition actions and the additional actions within the `IF-ELSE` block should be counted separately.

   See the reference here for more limits on Flow: [Limits for automated, scheduled, and instant flows.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/limits-and-config)